# simple client/server printing msg TCP in C

Tags: c, tcp, server, printf, client

I've recently started using TCP sockets in C(I'm still new to these) and after I figured out the theory behind them, I tried to make a simple server/client where the client takes a string from the server and then prints it.

Here's the code for the server :

```
//SERVER
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<string.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    
#include<errno.h>    
#include<netdb.h>    
#include<arpa/inet.h>    
#include<sys/wait.h>    
#include<signal.h>

#define BACKLOG 5

int main(){

    char *msg;

    int len, bytes_sent;

    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;

    socklen_t addr_size;

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    int sockfd,new_fd;


    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;

    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;


    getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "3940", &hints, &res);

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

    bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);


    if(listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == 0){

        printf("Listening\n");

        }

    else{

        printf("Error\n");

        exit(1);

        }


    addr_size = sizeof their_addr;

    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);

    strcpy(msg, "HELLO WORLD!");

    len = strlen(msg);

    bytes_sent = send(new_fd,msg,len,0);


    printf("\nMessage sent");

    close(new_fd);

    close(sockfd);

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the code for the client:

```
//CLIENT
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<signal.h>

int main(){

    int sockfd;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "3940", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

    connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);


    recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);

    printf("Data received: %s\n",buffer);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Now here's the problem. What it should happen is the client should print a simple `Data received : HELLO WORLD`. The point is it does that but also prints something else I don't understand and can't figure out why it does that. Here's the picture of the client's result(I'm using Linux on virtualbox)

[image]

As you can see after the HELLO WORLD, the client prints 3 more character.

I know the problem is probably a check I missed(or something like that) but as I've already stated I'm still new to this so I don't know what more to add or what I shouldn't put in the code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The client misses to `0`-terminate the "string" before printing it. It you do not know what this mean, better fall back to some more basic exercises before doing (more or less) complex network stuff.

Comment: BTW, `strlen()` returns `size_t`, `revc()` and `send()` both return `ssize_t`, none returns `int`. And not just the latter two require error checking, `recv()` even more has to have its return value to be checked in *any* case.